# error: request for member 'find' in '(cstring name)' which is of non-class type 'char [2000]'

Tags: find, c-strings

I'm sorry if this is vague I'm still pretty new to programming(also new to forums >_>)

Ok, my code is supposed to read in a number from a file, then use that number to read in that amount of words as dictionary words. I then store those words into an array and keep them for later usage. After the dictionary words in the file comes some paragraph, i read that in and set it to c-string array.(iv got that all down so far) But for the last part of the program i need to go back though that paragraph c-string and count how many times each dictionary word appears. I'm currently trying paragraph.find (word[0]) but i get some error that i don't know how to fix.

error: |40|error: request for member 'find' in 'paragraph', which is of non-class type 'char [2000]'|

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inStream;  //declare ifstream

    inStream.open("infile2.txt"); //open my file

    int number;                // number at the begining of the file that lets the     program know
    inStream >> number;        // how many dictionary words are to be expected.
    cout  << number << " dictionary word(s)" << endl << endl;

    char dict[30];
    char text[2000];
    char paragraph[2000];      // declareing some stuff
    int count;
    int position;
    string word[5];

    for (int i=0; i<number; i++)   // using c string to set the 'number' amount of words in the dict array
    {
        inStream.getline(dict,30,'|');
        word[i] = dict;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<number; i++)  // cout so i can see its all set up right.
    {
        cout << "word " << i+1 << " is: " << word[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    inStream.get(paragraph,2000,'|'); // setting the rest of the paragrapg of the txt   document to a c string
    cout << paragraph;                // so it can be searched later using the 'dict' words

   position = paragraph.find (word[0]);   // trying to find the position of the first word stored in 'dict[0]' but i run into an error

    return 0;
}
```

the infile2.txt looks like this:

3steak|eggs|and|

steak and eggs and eggs and steak, eggs and steak, steak and eggs...

delicious.

Answer (score 1):

c-strings are not classes and do not have a find method (or any other methods for that matter) i.e `paragraph.find`. You could try using a string or if you need to use c-strings a find method that takes two c strings as parameters.

such as [This one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)

Comment: ohhh i see the .find is a member. thanks for the link! i think i can understand that <3